# URL json found in browser, no found jquery

Tags: jquery, json, solr

I have made this function to treat data with **json** and I respond with an error **200**.

with the error resulting in the url in the browser works, but if I make the call to that function with jquery not working.

**the function:**

```
function solrQuery(query) {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost:8081/solr/select',
        type: "GET",
        data: {
            'q': query,
                'rows': "0",
                'facet.limit': "-1",
                'facet.mincount': "1",
                'facet': "true",
                'facet.field': "manufacturer",
                'wt': "json"
        },

        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            $('#cars').html('');

            if (button === 'listCars') {
                for (var i in data.facet_counts.facet_fields.manufacturer) {
                    //          if (!$.isNumeric(data.facet_counts.facet_fields.manufacturer[i])) {
                    var imagen = 'img/logo-cars/' + data.facet_counts.facet_fields.manufacturer[i] + '-logo-small.gif';
                    var dataImg = document.createElement('img');
                    $(dataImg).attr('src', imagen).attr('id', data.facet_counts.facet_fields.manufacturer[i]);
                    //          }
                    $('#cars').append(dataImg);

                }
            }
        },
        error: function (data) {
            alert("ccc");
        }
    });
}
```

**URL result of error:**

```
/solr/select?q=*%3A*&rows=0&facet.limit=-1&facet.mincount=1&facet=true&facet.field=manufacturer
```

This URL is correct, in browser found query JSON.

The result is:

```
{
    "responseHeader": {
        "status": 0,
        "QTime": 1,
        "params": {
            "facet": "true",
            "facet.mincount": "1",
            "q": "*:*",
            "facet.limit": "-1",
            "facet.field": "manufacturer",
            "wt": "json",
            "rows": "0"
        }
    },
    "response": {
        "numFound": 84,
        "start": 0,
        "docs": []
    },
    "facet_counts": {
        "facet_queries": {},
        "facet_fields": {
            "manufacturer": [
                "abarth",
                1,
                "audi",
                7,
                "austin",
                1,
                "bmw",
                2,
                "daewoo",
                2,
                "ford",
                1,
                "fso",
                1,
                "honda",
                1,
                "hyundai",
                1,
                "jaguar",
                3,
                "lexus",
                1,
                "mazda",
                1,
                "mitsubishi",
                1,
                "nissan",
                1,
                "pontiac",
                1,
                "seat",
                1
            ]
        },
        "facet_dates": {},
        "facet_ranges": {}
    }
}
```

No where can be the problem. Thanks.

Comment: If you remove `http://localhost:8081` (resulting in `url: '/solr/select',`, does the request still go to the same place? If not, then this is a cross-origin request and is not allowed due to the same-origin policy.

Comment: whats the response of the AJax query ????

Comment: yes, i removed http://localhost:8081 by answer. the original does. The response ajax is JSON, manufacturer data are valid.

Comment: The problem is http://localhost:8081.... changed by 'search-form', this is correct. Why it works?. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can use JSONP by replacing **dataType: 'json'** to **dataType: 'jsonp'** and add 
**jsonp: 'json.wrf',**

```
            function solrQuery(query) {
                $.ajax({
                url: 'http://localhost:8081/solr/select',
                type: "GET",
                data: {
                    'q': query,
                    'rows': "0",
                    'facet.limit': "-1",
                    'facet.mincount': "1",
                    'facet': "true",
                    'facet.field': "manufacturer",
                    'wt': "json"
                },
            //dataType: 'json', CHANGE FROM AJAX TO JSONP FOR CROSS DOMAIN ISSUE                       
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            jsonp: 'json.wrf',


                success: function (data) {
                    $('#cars').html('');

                    if (button === 'listCars') {
                    for (var i in data.facet_counts.facet_fields.manufacturer) {
                        //          if (!$.isNumeric(data.facet_counts.facet_fields.manufacturer[i])) {
                        var imagen = 'img/logo-cars/' + data.facet_counts.facet_fields.manufacturer[i] + '-logo-small.gif';
                        var dataImg = document.createElement('img');
                        $(dataImg).attr('src', imagen).attr('id', data.facet_counts.facet_fields.manufacturer[i]);
                        //          }
                        $('#cars').append(dataImg);

                    }
                    }
                },
                error: function (data) {
                    alert("ccc");
                }
                });
            }
```

Comment: The problem is the route, this is diferent. e.g: localhost:80 and localhost:8081.

Comment: Different browsers may consider a cross-port requests on the same host as either allowed or not, therefore your ajax call may fail. But [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) will work.